# Sorting number of tokens in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I have computed the count of words and characters from a column(String) having multiple records and have stored in two different columns. I would want to sort the count of number of words(token) in descending order.
ex:

CITY OF AMSTERDAM,3,17

```
token_map = {}
words = []

with open('test.csv', 'r') as fopen:
    lines = fopen.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = str.strip(line)
        words_in_line = str.split(line, " ")
        token_map[line] = "" + str(len(words_in_line)) +","+ str(len(line))
        words.append(words_in_line)


print words
print token_map
```

Comment: What? Why would a `DataFrame`  be the only (or even a good) solution? What exactly are you trying to count, because it doesn't look li've you've counted *tokens* at all. Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you need to give some background and define your goals clearly.

Comment: You actually don't sort at all. And there's no dataframe. Could you elaborate what you want to do and how you would do it with a dataframe (the sorting)?

Comment: New to python, so just figuring out stuffs. Can you please let me know how i can sort it?

Comment: a [mcve] would help!

Comment: @HarishKrishnan how you would sort *what*?. You need to adequately specify what you are doing. You've posted code with no context, we cannot possibly know what you really want. We don't know the contents of your file. Again, see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A good first step is to define an example input and a desired output.

Comment: But essentially, sorting some count of something is a very basic python operation, no need for `pandas` simply for that.

Comment: Hope my framing of the question is better now.

Comment: You've saved your counts as a *string* which is not very useful. Likely, you want to re-think your data structure so that it will be useful for actually using the numerical data (which you want to save as `int`).

Comment: oh okay, I will figure that out. Thanks :)

Comment: The simplest, although maybe not the best, way would be to do something like `token_map[line] = (len(words_in_line), len(line))` so now your map values are a tuple of word-count and line length. You have to remember the order here, and make sure it stays consistent, but for this simple example this would work fine I guess. Then it is a matter of sorting the output however you want. There are probably 1000s of questions on sorting in Python already, so this will probably become a duplicate.

Comment: Also, pro-tip, Don't do `lines = fopen.readlines()`, just iterate directly over `for line in fopen:`, this way it is lazy and memory efficient, and you won't unnecessarily load the entire file into memory.

Comment: I did try a few of them, but didn't work. Thanks for replying, will keep digging in.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running examples make a big difference. I made up some data and then applied the `sorted` function to your `dict` and got its items in ascending order. You can add `reverse=True` if you want it the other way.

```
token_map = {}
words = []

lines = ['I am the very model\n', 'of the modern\n', 'major general\n']

for line in lines:
    line = str.strip(line)
    words_in_line = str.split(line, " ")
    token_map[line] = "" + str(len(words_in_line)) +","+ str(len(line))
    words.append(words_in_line)

print words
print token_map

for item in sorted(token_map.iteritems(), key=lambda item: int(item[1].split(',')[0])):
    print item
```

The way you've chosen to store data seems odd. If you use a `tuple` with the count as its first item, the sort is more straight forward.

```
token_map = {}
words = []

for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    words_in_line = line.split(" ")
    token_map[line] = (len(words_in_line), line)

for value in sorted(token_map.values()):
    print(value)
```